# symfony2 session persistance

Tags: php, symfony, session

This has been bugging me for a week now.

I cant seem to get a large php array to persist in the session over a page redirect.

```
for ($i=1;$i<$data['weeks'];$i++) {
    $instances[] = array(
        'start' => $startTime + ((86400 * 7) * $i),
        'end'   => $startTime + ((86400 * 7) * $i) + $duration,
        'venueId' => $data['venueId']
    );
}

$request->getSession()->set('addClass-1-instances', $instances);

return new RedirectResponse ($this->generateUrl(
    'class_add', array(
        'clubId' => $this->club->clubId,
        'step' => 4,
        'classType' => 1
    )
));
```

This works when the array is really small (1-10 elements) but fails when it is larger (1000 - 2000 elements).

If I dump out the session object after adding it, I can see that it is in the session attributes collection.

```
var_dump($request->getSession());

protected 'attributes' => &
    array (size=6)
        'addClass-1-instances' => 
            array (size=1560)
                0 => ...
```

But once the page is redirected, the session appears to be totally empty.

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag)[487]
    private 'name' => string 'attributes' (length=10)
    private 'storageKey' => string '_sf2_attributes' (length=15)
    protected 'attributes' => &
        array (size=0)
            empty
```

We store our sessions in the database, and it works fine throughout the rest of the webapp. I've read all over the place and seen people talk about the session.save-dir php option, but am I not right to think this is irrelevant when using DB storage.

Help!

Not sure how to solve this. The session ids remain the same on both the pages, and theres no code that explicitly clears the session.

Not sure where to go not but here!

Comment: Does the data exist in database a) just after you set it b) after you try to fetch it without success ? What type is session_value column in session table?

Comment: I can see the timestamp in the db update, and the amount of data greatly increases. the field is type TEXT, so no limit on size.

Comment: And after the page changes, the data disappears from the session_value field.